How can i use jq to format json to csv?
I am trying to format this json data to CSV format, but I get this error: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "time". 
Here is a short version of my json data:
{
  "latitude": 52.52,
  "longitude": 13.419998,
  "generationtime_ms": 0.23293495178222656,
  "utc_offset_seconds": 7200,
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "timezone_abbreviation": "CEST",
  "elevation": 38.0,
  "daily_units": {
    "time": "iso8601",
    "weather_code": "wmo code",
    "temperature_2m_max": "°F",
    "temperature_2m_min": "°F",
    "precipitation_probability_max": "%"
  },
  "daily": {
    "time": [
      "2024-10-13",
      "2024-10-14"
    ],
    "weather_code": [
      80,
      61
    ],
    "temperature_2m_max": [
      52.7,
      53.1
    ],
    "temperature_2m_min": [
      48.6,
      43.7
    ],
    "precipitation_probability_max": [
      100,
      10
    ]
  }
}

I want it to be formatted like this:
time,weather_code,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,precipitation_probability_max
2024-10-13,80,52.7,48.6,100
2024-10-14,61,53.1,43.7,10

This is the command I wrote, but I get the error jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "time". This also happens with each field if i delete all the previous ones.
curl -s "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&daily=weather_code,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,precipitation_probability_max&temperature_unit=fahrenheit&wind_speed_unit=mph&precipitation_unit=inch&timezone=auto&forecast_days=14" | 

jq -r '
  [
    "date", "weather_code", "temperature_2m_max", "temperature_2m_min", "precipitation_probability_max"
  ],
  .daily |
  [
    .time[],
    .weather_code[],
    .temperature_2m_max[],
    .temperature_2m_min[],
    .precipitation_probability_max[]
  ]
  | @csv
'

I tried to change the "time" field to a Unix timestamp, but I am still not sure how to get it to work, because it throws the same error.

You need transpose function:
curl -s "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&daily=weather_code,temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,precipitation_probability_max&temperature_unit=fahrenheit&wind_speed_unit=mph&precipitation_unit=inch&timezone=auto&forecast_days=14" | 
jq -r '([ "date", "weather_code", "temperature_2m_max", "temperature_2m_min", "precipitation_probability_max"],
        ([.daily[]] | transpose[])
       ) | @csv'


It worked for me, thanks so much!

@featherlessbiped Fell free to accept the answer.
